# deploy Apache ServiceMix 4 application into JBoss Application Server 7

Tags: maven, jboss, cxf, apache-servicemix, dosgi

I have an standalone [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) 4.4 application, it works nicely. Now, I want to deploy this application inside a [JBoss Application Server 7](http://www.jboss.org/as7). I use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as project and dependency management tool.

My objective is deploying the application not touching any line of code, only [maven POM files](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html). I can add new dependencies, change some versions (minor) and use different tools. I want, as a second objective, integrate all the [Apache CXF DOSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html) container features into JBoss AS ones seamlessly.

I think it is possible, but I found information for old releases of JBoss and ServiceMix or incomplete guides like [this](https://community.jboss.org/thread/174136).

Can someone provide more information about that?

**EDIT**

I have found some issues in JBoss issue tracker:
[Initial runtime support for Karaf based products](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5544)

And some JBoss forum topics:
[Migrating osgi bundles running in Karaf  to JBoss 7 as OSGI container](https://community.jboss.org/thread/213147)

I forgot to mention that my application is using [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) OSGi runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Well Servicemix is "pre-"setup of a Container (Apache Karaf) and lot's of other Apache Projects like ActiveMq and Camel plus some ServiceMix specialties. So why would you want to deploy this setup in another Container?
If you want to do something like this, try to deploy std. Apache Camel, ActiveMQ and CXF and your own app in JBoss.

Comment: then, do you recommend I use JBoss as container and not use Apache Karaf? can I setup a container-in-container solution?

Comment: Nope I wouldn't recommend using JBoss, but that depends completely on your use-case and if a Apache Karaf as container is accepted. I'd leave the setup as is, since that is tested environment. A setup for Container-in-Container, that's something I can not recommend at all.

Comment: I edited my question. using Karaf as OSGi runtime inside JBoss AS could be a solution, but it is still being developed and will be fully completed in JBoss AS 8. anyway I think I can use it in JBoss AS 7 now.

Comment: I know there is a sample on how to embed a Karaf Container inside another container, but I still don't see the point in doing so. Karaf gives all the features required to run the targeted Software, and by doing this with a much smaller footprint. Though this is solely up to you.

Comment: I have followed the guidelines explained in the JBoss issue "Initial runtime support for Karaf based products" and I have achieved running Karaf inside Jboss. now I will try to execute my app and solve some errors I get. having Karaf inside JBoss is a requirement in my project. thank you very much.